# How to create a Android notification with support to older API levels (e.g. lvl 23)

Tags: android, api, notifications, backwards-compatibility

Maybe this issue is way simpler than I expected it to be: I want to display a `notification`, created within the `onCreate` function of an `Activity` (for debugging reasons).

`Android Studio 3.0.1`, Api lvl 23 (to support older devices) and running on a Nexus5 device with Api lvl 27.

**The Code to display a notification:**

```
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setTicker("SomethingTicker")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.someImage)
            .setContentTitle("SomeTitle")
            .setContentText("SomeText")
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(001, notification);
```

Which shows that `NotificationCompat.Builder` with only the the context is deprecated. I should use a Notification Channel within the newer version.

**The issue:** To create and register a NotificationChannel I have to use api lvl >27.

What am I missing? And what is the best way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to display a notification, created within the onCreate function of an Activity.

Note that this is an odd time to display a `Notification`.

> What am I missing?

You need code to create the `NotificationChannel` that will only run on Android 8.0+ devices:

```
NotificationManager mgr=
  (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O &&
  mgr.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_WHATEVER)==null) {
  mgr.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_WHATEVER,
    "Whatever", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT));
}
```

Then, for all API levels, pass in your channel identifier (here, `CHANNEL_WHATEVER`) to the `NotificationCompat.Builder` constructor. On older devices, the channel will be ignored.

Comment: Note: The creation time was more or less for debugging reasons. It makes sense to set it as an optional parameter. Thank you ;)

Comment: @schlenger: "The creation time was more or less for debugging reasons" -- ah, OK.

Comment: What a mess....